# Why does compiler complain about ambiguous overload for assignment operator?

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading

(As the title suggests, the question is here is more about why compiler raises ambiguity issue when line [1] presents, not on the overall architecture.)

In header file, class `Person` is the base class to all person-related classes. Class `Student` is derived from `Person`. On line [1], it has a template constructor that may allow recursive constructor call. It also has a default copy assignment operator (line [2]) and a copy assignment operator that accepts a shared pointer typed as `Person`.

Looks like line [1] causes problems and it "interferes" with copy assignment operator call. See the following.

In `ambiguous_overload.hpp`:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class Person;

class Student;

class Person {
protected:
    std::string name;
public:
    Person() {}
    virtual ~Person() {}
};


class Student : public Person {
public:
    Student();

    template<typename... Args> Student(Args... args) { // [1]
        // ...;
    }

    Student(const Student&);                            
    Student(const std::shared_ptr<Student>);
    Student(const std::shared_ptr<Person>);
    ~Student();

    Student& operator=(const Student&);                 // [2]  
    Student& operator=(const std::shared_ptr<Student>);
    Student& operator=(const std::shared_ptr<Person>);   //[3]
};
```

In `ambiguous_overload.cpp`, the implementation is rather standard except a derived class `Child` has been implemented at [4]. When testing the copy assignment operator of `Student`, I created a shared pointer pointing to `Child` and assigned it to an instance of `Student`.

```
#include "ambiguous_overload.hpp"

Student::Student() {}
Student::Student(const Student& stu) {}
Student::Student(const std::shared_ptr<Student> ptr) {}
Student::Student(const std::shared_ptr<Person> ptr) {}
Student::~Student(){}

Student& Student::operator=(const Student& stu) {
    //...;
    return *this;
}
Student& Student::operator=(const std::shared_ptr<Student> ptr) {
    //...;
    return *this;
}
Student& Student::operator=(const std::shared_ptr<Person> ptr) {
    //...;
    return *this;
}


class Child : public Person {    // [4]
public:
    Child() {}
};

int main() {
    [](){
        Student stu;
        std::shared_ptr<Child> child_ptr (new Child());   // [5]
        stu = child_ptr;    // [6] Ambiguous overload (if line [1] stays)
    } ();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler, however, raises the following error.

```
./ambiguous_overload.cpp:26:15: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Student’ and ‘std::shared_ptr<Child>’)
   26 |         stu = child_ptr;
      |               ^~~~~~~~~
./ambiguous_overload.cpp:12:10: note: candidate: ‘Student& Student::operator=(const Student&)’
   12 | Student& Student::operator=(const Student& stu) { return *this; }
      |          ^~~~~~~
./ambiguous_overload.cpp:14:10: note: candidate: ‘Student& Student::operator=(std::shared_ptr<Person>)’
   14 | Student& Student::operator=(const std::shared_ptr<Person> ptr) { return *this; }
      |          ^~~~~~~
```

Line [1] appears to be the smoking gun: When it is removed, compiler is silent and there is no error on ambiguity. It suggests that somewhere in invoking the copy assignment operator, the constructor is (perhaps) called.

But, I don't quite understand the ambiguity here.
First of all, all copy assignment operators are returning reference type `Student&`, not values, and are (perhaps?) needing no constructor calls. Second, the default copy assignment operator takes a reference of `Student` type, yet on the right hand side of [6] a shared pointer to `Child` is provided, i.e. not subclass of `Student`. Moreover, at line [6], the object `stu` on the left hand side has already been constructed, requiring no (perhaps) constructor call.

**Update** Inspired by the comment from Igor Tandetnik, I found that making constructors `explicit` dismisses this ambiguity issue.

Comment: I've never heard of `operator=>` that's referenced in the compiler's error message.

Comment: I think you're approaching this the wrong way. At the moment, you can assign a `Student` to a `Person`, which leads to slicing. Also, those assignment operators are picked at compile time, so even if the LHS was actually a `Student`, it would still only copy the `Student`. Treat those classes as non-assignable or at least assert the same type during assignment and then delegate to a virtual function.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt Thanks for raising the object slicing issue. At this moment, my question is more on what exactly happens upon calling the copy assignment operator when line [1] presents.

Comment: Looks very similar to OP's deleted question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70224925/why-does-compiler-complain-ambiguous-overlod-for-operator?noredirect=1#comment124139046_70224925).

Comment: `stu = child_ptr` can be interpreted two ways: `stu.operator=(std::shared_ptr<Person>(child_ptr))` or `stu.operator=(Student(child_ptr))` . Neither is better than the other. Hence the ambiguity. `Student(child_ptr)` is enabled by that templated constructor that takes anything.

Comment: @Anoop Rana Yes. But that question was not properly formulated/edited and was thus removed for good.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Could you please substantiate your comment? Especially the interpretation process, as you mentioned "interpreted [in] two ways". That appears to be the key.

Comment: Class hierarchies should disable copying and assignment, these operations just make no sense (you can have a clone function instead). Class hierarchies also need proper virtual functions to make sense (not just a virtual destructor).

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. I understand. Hierarchy wise, this example may not make sense. What I don't understand is the ambiguity issue raise by the compiler, it doesn't seem to have much to do with hierarchy design but the presence of line [1]. Any thought on that?

Comment: Well you have your class student constructible from anything whatsoever. This isn't really a real-world situation. Why do you need this constructor? What does it do?

Comment: That's just [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) 101. The compiler tries each of the three overloads of `Student::operator=`. None match the type of the argument exactly, but two of them can match it after a user-defined conversion is applied. You've added a [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) that allows anything at all to be implicitly converted to `Student`.